# Create an instance based on condition via returned generic T type

Tags: c#, generics, c#-4.0, collections

I have different classes with same property names.

I get data and assign to those properties based on conditions, for example

```
if age<10  
var ClassA = new ClassA();
ClassA.Percent =25;  
ClassA.StandarValue=1000;

if age > 25  
var ClassB = new ClassB();
ClassB.Percent =15;  
ClassB.StandarValue=3000;
```

I can write a method

```
public T ReturnMyCustomClass(int age)
{ if age< 10  
    return (T)(object)ClassA; 
if age> 25  
   return (T)(object)ClassB;
throw new Exception();
}
```

I can assign that as

var result=ReturnMyCustomClass(26);

Question:

```
if (result is ClassA)
```

how can i assign 
`var myClass=new result();` --this is wrong, but how can I create an instance from returned object above?

Comment: Take a look at Activator.CreatInstance. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: You code will not compile, please provide minimal reproducible sample

Comment: `var myClass = Activator.CreateInstance(result.GetType());`